# Linq to EF sometimes slow and sometimes not

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Why does this line sometimes perform well and sometimes not at all well?

```
var messages = db.Items.Where(b => 
                              b.Date == selectedDate && 
                              b.Country == selectedCountry).ToList();
```

even for identical selectedDate, selectedCountry and no apparent change to the database.
When it is slow, I see no particular load on either the computer running this line or on the SQL Server computer.

If I just break and restart the application when it is slow, it sometimes manages to do that line quickly instead. And sometimes it is simply fast.

If I change it to the following:

```
 var messages = db.Messages.Where(b => 
                                  b.Date == selectedDate && 
                                  b.Country == selectedCountry);
 foreach (var message in messages) 
 {
     ddlMessages.Items.Add(messages.Name);
 }
```

I still have the same problem, but the slow line being the one starting with `ddlMessages`, i.e., where the application actually reads from the DB.

My select returns about 400 items.

Update:

I have a clustered index on Date,Country,Name.

When I run the query in management studio it took 2 seconds, each of the about 20 times that I tried. This is about the time it takes in the application too, when it is fast.
When it is slow, I wait for about a minute before I break it in the debugger to see what it is doing.

When the application is

Before `foreach`, `messages` contains:

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
[Extent1].[Country] AS [Country], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Extent1].[Data] AS [Data]
FROM [dbo].[Message] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Date] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Country] = @p__linq__1)}
```

The database context is new and has not been used before this query.

Comment: What do you mean "slow" and "fast"? How do you measure speed of this code? Could you show us sql query that is in messages before foreach statement? Do you have indexes in db on Date or Country columns?

Comment: Are you reusing the context for multiple queries? also is this the first query you are doing?

Comment: Have you tried running your query directly in your database? It seems to me that you could use a non-clustered index on `(Date, Country)`.

Comment: 2 seconds is incredibly slow for a clustered index scan that returns ~400 rows. This should execute in the blink of an eye on a non-taxed server. Check the 'Actual Query Plan' in SSMS to confirm that SQL Server is using a clustered index scan. If they query plan looks okay, start looking into your network for issues.

Comment: The column 'Data' is huge. Since I do not need it in this case, if I do not select that column the query takes 0 seconds according to the SSMS.